# Impala SQL with Multiple Count Distinct - Help Needed

Tags: impala

We have been trying hard for last several weeks for finding solution to a impala sql query problem.

We are looking forward for any guidance or advise on this situation.

Below is table for our requirement (also Image attached).

we need to report counts against each endpoint_type.

In my case its NAS and Remote Site. We need following counts.

1. Count of devices - We need count distinct of number of devices for each endpoint_type. This would be unique count of device.

Values Expected

NAS - 6

Remote Site - 4

2. Count of Shares - This field is distinct combination of (device,datacenter,share)

Values Expected

NAS - 6

Remote Site - 5

3. Count of folders - This field is distinct combination of (device,datacenter,share,folder_name) where folder_type=regular

Values Expected

NAS - 3

Remote Site - 2

4. Count of Open Folders - This field is distinct combination of (device,datacenter,share,folder_name) where folder_type=regular and open_status = Open

Values Expected

NAS - 2

Remote Site - 1

5. Count of Remediated Folders - This field is distinct combination of (device,datacenter,share,folder_name) where folder_type=regular and open_status = Open and remediated = YES

Values Expected

NAS - 2

Remote Site - 0

Since Impala throw error for multiple count distincts with different column combinations we are not able to do this in a query.

We even tried multiple queries and joining them but results did not come correctly.

When we get the count , we also need to show the records that make up that count.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Sudi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjJjP.jpg)